# Update Statement MySQL Consecutive Fields

Tags: mysql

Having the mysql process below, would it be reasonable to say that always mysql will update first than then second column, if I maintain the order below (given the dependency). or is it recommended that I write 2 separate update queries one for the first column and one for the second?

```
CREATE TABLE a (first INT, second INT);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,1);
UPDATE a SET first = 2, second = first * 2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sequential. So, first gets updated to 2 and then second gets updated to first * 2 = 4.

If your data was 1, 1, after your update, it will be:

```
CREATE TABLE a (first INT, second INT);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,1);
UPDATE a SET first = 2, second = first * 2;
select * from a;
+-------+--------+
| first | second |
+-------+--------+
|     2 |      4 |
+-------+--------+
```

If you do this:

```
truncate table a;
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,1);
UPDATE a SET second = first * 2, first = 2;
```

you will get

```
select * from a;
+-------+--------+
| first | second |
+-------+--------+
|     2 |      2 |
+-------+--------+
```

So, if you want to update the second field (which relies on dependent field), change the order of the second field to be ahead of the dependent field.

Comment: thank you for you explanation I will accept this answer once the 6 minute timer finishes